# Graphviz and Dot and graphs with hundreds of nodes.

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a number of graphs I'd like to render with 150 to 750 nodes and about 3 times that many edges.

The graphs have a time component, and so I have been (with smaller, say 20 node samples), been using rank same to gather them by day.

dot does a very nice job rendering these smaller graphs. However, there seems to be a point where things just get very, very slow, or dot just outright dumps core and says "move along".

sfdp and neato will render these graphs, but they are a giant mess, when in fact, I know that they could be rendered into a nice looking flow chart.

Any advice? How can I get dot rendering these, or find another tool that can do a directed graph? Is rank same killing me here?

Here is sample output from my current run, which is 20 minutes in, and shows no signs of finishing..

```
network simplex:  188 nodes 487 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=1
network simplex: 188 nodes 487 edges 0 iter 0.00 sec
Maxrank = 561, minrank = 0
mincross: pass 0 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 0 best_cross 0
mincross: pass 0 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 4084 best_cross 4084
mincross: pass 0 iter 1 trying 0 cur_cross 3308 best_cross 3308
mincross: pass 0 iter 2 trying 0 cur_cross 1552 best_cross 1552
mincross: pass 0 iter 3 trying 0 cur_cross 1409 best_cross 1409
mincross: pass 1 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 5183 best_cross 840
mincross: pass 1 iter 1 trying 1 cur_cross 4156 best_cross 840
mincross: pass 1 iter 2 trying 2 cur_cross 2003 best_cross 840
mincross: pass 1 iter 3 trying 3 cur_cross 1780 best_cross 840
mincross: pass 2 iter 0 trying 0 cur_cross 840 best_cross 840
mincross: pass 2 iter 1 trying 1 cur_cross 946 best_cross 840
mincross: pass 2 iter 2 trying 2 cur_cross 922 best_cross 840
mincross: pass 2 iter 3 trying 0 cur_cross 774 best_cross 774
mincross: pass 2 iter 4 trying 0 cur_cross 629 best_cross 629
mincross: pass 2 iter 5 trying 1 cur_cross 759 best_cross 629
```

...

```
mincross: pass 2 iter 19 trying 3 cur_cross 567 best_cross 438
mincross: pass 2 iter 20 trying 4 cur_cross 507 best_cross 438
network simplex:  135708 nodes 203040 edges maxiter=2147483647 balance=2  
network simplex: 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000   
network simplex: 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 1700 1800 1900 2000   
network simplex: 2100 2200 2300 2400 2500 2600 2700 2800 2900 3000   
network simplex: 3100 3200 3300 3400 3500 3600 3700 3800 3900 4000   
network simplex: 4100 4200 4300 4400 4500 4600 4700 4800 4900 5000   
network simplex: 5100 5200 5300 5400 5500 5600 5700 5800 5900 6000
```

... currently at 321,200

Comment: I agree that `rank = same` adds constraints that could prevent `dot` from finding a solution. Does `dot` render the same graph if `rank = same` is omitted from the graph file? Otherwise you might have to edit your question to include the smallest file that `dot` can't render so we can look at it line-by-line for potential problems. Of course, it might be that the graph is just too complicated for `dot` or `dot` doesn't perceive the overall structure in the graph that would let it produce a good rendering.

Comment: I've been experimenting with shrinking the number of  `rank = same` statements, and that seems to speed things up a lot. It seems that time grows at least on the order of n^2 with number of `rank = same` statements. The file did render in the end; it took about 20 minutes on a v3 xeon, crashing cairo: 32k x 25k or so image. The SVG renderer worked, yielding a graph with some problems. I will keep experimenting and leave this open for the time being, and report back with results.

Answer (score 0):

Just to finish up here, I would now advise against using rank=same with even 'small to medium' graphs, call it more than 100 nodes.

We are instead internally ordering node creation in our files to encourage a sort of soft ranking, and using source and sink to try and get some order in shape.

Anecdotally, it seems there's probably quite a lot of original research waiting to be done in algorithms for laying out and flowing these, so if you're a graduate student looking for a thesis, this is an area that hasn't received a ton of attention in the last 10 years, at least.